# Nuxt Firebase Authentication Middleware

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt(vue) as frontend and Firestore and Authentication as Backend. I got the authentication to work to a certain amount, but my problem is refreshing the browser resets the state so my Middleware returns a false  result.

Here some code snippets:

Middleware:

```
export default function ({store, redirect, route}) {

    const userIsLoggedIn = !!store.state.currentUser; 

    if(!userIsLoggedIn) {
        return redirect ('/')
    } 
}
```

Plugin:

```
import { auth } from '@/services/firebaseInit.js'

export default (context) => {
    const { store } = context

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            store.commit('setCurrentUser', user)
            resolve()
        })
    })
}
```

Now this works in running App but when someone refreshes a page where you need auth it doesnt work and redirect to /, now i dont know how to solve that, would appreciate help and if you need more code then i provide it.

EDIT 1:

```
   async nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
            let user = await firebase.auth().currentUser

            commit('setCurrentUser', user)
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to init your user in [nuxtServerInit](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action) method, otherwise your middleware will be executed on server with empty user and hence redirect will happen.

You need to grab user data from req object. See this repo for reference implementation https://github.com/davidroyer/nuxt-ssr-firebase-auth.v2

Comment: May i ask for further introduction? I edited my post with my further solution attempts based on your answer.

Comment: @Badgy and where from firbase.aut().currentUser supposed to get current user? Obviously there wont be anything on server. You need to grab required data from req object. See this repo for some references https://github.com/davidroyer/nuxt-ssr-firebase-auth.v2

Comment: Thanks for the link and your time!